# How to check if specific overload of an operator exists at compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I have a class which overloads the () operator for multiple input types i.e.

```
struct Type {
    void operator()(int);
    void operator()(std::string);
};
```

Now, I would like to use SFINAE to check if a specific overload of () operator exists or not i.e.

```
if (Type()(std::string) overload exists) {
    // do something...
}
```

Is this possible to do in C++11? (I cannot use C++14 or C++17).

Note: In the actual code, there is a template class which accepts a class type with certain properties. There is a member function in this template which will be specialized based on whether certain specific overloads of () operator for the parameter type exists or not.

Comment: Do you want to check for an overload with an exact parameter type? Or do you want to know if `operator()` is callable with with a specific parameter type (possibly using implicit conversions)?

Comment: I would prefer exact parameter type. Although the latter should do as well.

Comment: How about something like `std::is_invocable`?  (You can implement one if you don't have C++17.)

Comment: I just took a look at invocable, seems I can use it, just have to make sure of compiler compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

Use SFINAE to check if it's possible to make a pointer-to-member to the overload of `operator()` you're looking for.

Here is how I would do it:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename A, typename B, typename = void>
struct has_overload : std::false_type {};
template <typename A, typename B>
struct has_overload<A, B, decltype((void)(void (A::*)(B))&A::operator())> : std::true_type {};
```

Usage: `has_overload<Type, std::string>::value`.

Comment: Can you explain what `decltype((void)(void (A::*)(B))&A::operator())` does?

Comment: First, `&A::operator()` attempts to form a pointer-to-member to `operator()` from class `A`. Because `operator()` is overloaded, we have to immediately cast the pointer-to-member to select a specific overload: `(void (A::*)(B))`. Then, the result is casted to `void`, to make `decltype` evaluate to `void`.

Answer (score 2):

In first step I would restrict `Type::opeator()` to take only particular types, i.e. `int` and `string`.

```
struct Type {
    void operator()(int) {}
    void operator()(std::string) {}

    template<class U>
    void operator()(U) = delete;
};
```

In this way we disable implicit conversions.

Then we could write class template something like this:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct canInvokeFor : std::false_type {};

template<class Arg>
struct canInvokeFor< Arg, decltype ( std::declval<Type>().operator ()(Arg{}) ) > 
   : std::true_type {};
```

in the specialization of which we emulate invoking `operator()` for passed `Arg` type.
Results:

```
struct Foo {};
std::cout << canInvokeFor<int>::value << std::endl; // 1
std::cout << canInvokeFor<std::string>::value << std::endl; // 1
std::cout << canInvokeFor<float>::value << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << canInvokeFor<char>::value << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << canInvokeFor<Foo>::value << std::endl; // 0
```

[Demo under c++11](https://godbolt.org/z/gUtiuj)

Comment: There are many cases when things like `canInvokeFor` are included before including struct declaration. So it depends on declaration (or include) order. And if this order is wrong -- it will not compile in GCC. (In MSVC works fine)